# Run javascript function IN the middle of Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

here is the problem: I have an Ajax.ActionLink() in which I need to provide a value from textbox for routeValues:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Purchase Tracking", "StatusOfFactor", "Shopping", new { guid = HERE I WANT A JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION TO RETRIEVE VALUE FROM TEXTBOX } , ajaxOptions: new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "StatusOfFactor", HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btnpeyment btn btn-xs bg-color-btn" })
```

how should I implement it?

Comment: Instead of making the function there, why not just add an event listener on change of a textbox; so that everytime it changes, it'll update the actionlink. Don't ask the actionlink to look for a textbox change; rather tell the text box to inform the actionlink when it is changed

Comment: Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the `Ajax.ActionLink` and write some javascript code yourself to achieve what you are after.

To start, we will replace the Ajax action link with a normal anchor tag

```
<a id="purchasTrackingLink" class="btnpeyment"
                    href="@Url.Action("StatusOfFactor","Shopping")">Purchase Tracking</a>
<input id="YourTextBoxId" />
```

Now wireup the click event on this link, prevent the default behavior, read the value of your textbox and use that to generate the new target url and use that for the ajax call.p

```
$(function(){

   $("#purchasTrackingLink").click(function(e){

       e.preventDefault();

       var textBoxVal=$("#YourTextBoxId").val();
       var url=$(this).attr("href");
       url=url+"?guid="+textBoxVal;
       //Now make the ajax call
       $.get(url,function(response){
          $("#StatusOfFactor").html(response);
       });

   });

});
```

Comment: thank u very much for your nice and clear and well explained solution. MUCHAS GRACIAS

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#textBoxID').on('change', function(event){
   var value = $('#textBoxID').val();
   $('#ajaxLinkID').attr('guid', value);
})
```

Replace the IDs with the ones you are using.

Note: If the textbox was placed on the page via an AJAX call, you will need to use event delegation to make this work, delegate it to the parent container that was originally loaded on the page.